# How can I use a proxy server, without installing any software

Tags: proxy, privileges

I'd like to use a proxy when I browse websites for example. But I've no administrator-privilegs to install any software.

Is there a way to use a proxy(for example the google-proxy) without the requirement of installing any software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use a service called gmodules.

**What is Gmodules?**
Gmodules is actually just a website-url: `http://www.gmodules.com/ig/proxy?url=http://YourDomain` to which you have to attach your url to visit a website with the google proxy. Gmodules works on all operating systems, because it doesnt require any software installed.

Follow these steps to use the **google proxy** without installing any software:

1. Find a website you want to visit with a proxy. For example:

   > http://www.google.ch
2. Now you have to use the gmodules-service. 
   Gmodules provides a url you have to attach your url to. For example:

   > http://www.gmodules.com/ig/proxy?url=http://www.google.ch

   As you see, I've attached the url which I want to visit, to the gmodules-url. So If you now open the url, the website will think, the google proxy connects to it.